# Override CustomerController of Prestashop in 17.6.1

Tags: controller, overriding, prestashop

I tried to add a new feature in my Prestashop 1.7.6 (allow to detect the change of group of a client since the backoffice).

I think I have to override a feature that I find in the CustomerController.php located in "src /PrestaShopBundle/Controller/Admin/Sell/Customer/CustomerController.php ".

How can I overload this controller, I tried to create a file in "override / controllers / admin" but it did not work ?

Comment: Make sure you clear the cache every time you override something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in `/src` folder can not be overrided:

[Understanding the “src” folder](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/architecture/understanding-src-folder/)

[Overrides](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/architecture/understanding-src-folder/)

If you want to detect the change of group of a client, you can use hook `actionCustomerBeforeUpdateGroup`, which is called at `classes/Customer`:

```
public function updateGroup($list)
{
    Hook::exec('actionCustomerBeforeUpdateGroup', array('id_customer' => $this->id, 'groups' => $list));
    if ($list && !empty($list)) {
        $this->cleanGroups();
        $this->addGroups($list);
    } else {
        $this->addGroups(array($this->id_default_group));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i thought... Do you have any ideas, how can I detect the chane change group of a client since the backoffice ?

Answer (score 0):

If the change added in the override is not visible you have to delete the var/cache/prod/class_index.php or var/cache/dev/class_index.php depending on your environment. No worries, it'll be recreated.

Comment: yes I tried... It seems src folder can not be overrided

Comment: yes, the classes in src cannot be overriden but the the legacy ones in ps_root/ classes and ps_root.controllers can. You may find something you can use there. There are some Customer classes in ps_root/classes. Alternatively you can develop a module and extend the src functionality there.